# What version of CMIS Workbench contains TCK unit tests for CMIS 1.0?

Tags: cmis, opencmis, cmis-workbench

I want to unit test a repository for CMIS 1.0 compatibility.

If I use the latest [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html), then the TCK button runs the unit tests for CMIS 1.1 (which fails, since the repository only supports CMIS 1.0).

Is there some way to run the TCK CMIS 1.0 unit tests even with the latest CMIS Workbench?

If not, [what version of CMIS Workbench](http://archive.apache.org/dist/chemistry/opencmis/) was the last before they switched to the CMIS 1.1 TCK unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCK automatically adapts to the repository. If the repository reports (in the repository info) that it is a CMIS 1.0 repository, only CMIS 1.0 tests will be executed. If the repository reports that it is a CMIS 1.1 repository, then CMIS 1.1 tests will be executed. All CMIS Workbench versions since 0.9.0-beta-1 do that.

If a TCK test fails, it's either a repository issue or the repository reports the wrong CMIS version.